# How to change colour of boxes in a grid

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onclick, grid

I've created a grid with boxes in it that each has an id of box + i. However when i try to add an on click function to change the colour of the box it doesn't allow me to. Here is the code:

```
function Board() {
    
    var rows = []
    var numrows = 1000;
    for(var i = 0; i < numrows; i++){
        rows.push(<Box id={"box" + i}  tabIndex="0" onClick={
            document.getElementById(`box${i}`).style.backgroundColor = "red"

        } className="box"  />);
    }

    return (
       <GameBoard>
           {rows}
       </GameBoard>
    )
}
```

export default Board

Comment: What happens? Do you see an error in the logs? What si the color in the beginning and what happens after you click? Those details are useful when we dont have access to the whole code.

Comment: It says TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null in the logs. The box colours are white and is expected to turn red on click. However this error appears before i'm even able to click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onClick` prop on `Box` should be a function

```js
<Box
 id={"box" + i}
 tabIndex="0"
 onClick={() => {
            document.getElementById(`box${i}`).style.backgroundColor = "red"
        }
 }
 className="box"
/>
```

PS: Don't forget to use the id prop in actual DOM element e.g. in definition of Box component

```js
const Box = ({id, /*... rest props*/}) => {
   return (
      <div id={id}> {/* assign ID to real DOM node so it's accessible in document.getElementById*/}
       {/* rest of the Box component definition*/}
      </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: Yes im sorry i forgot to add that in to the code i showed but even with that it lets me click on the box which changes the colour how i want but then produces: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.

Comment: can you update the code? Also if you're getting `document.getElementById(...)` is null then the ID you're providing is incorrect. You can use browser's debugger to step through the code to see what ID is being passed and then see it on the elements tab if it event exists.

Comment: here's a codesandbox which works on top of what code you've provided. See Board component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/async-flower-e3srz

Comment: Thank you, this fixes my problem that i've been try to solve for some time. I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. I also agree with other answers - that is to use state hooks instead of `document.getElementById` to set color value. Because that is the React way. Mixing imperative programming with declarative programming isn't really a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `state` in the `Box` component & toggle that locally:

```js
const { useState } = React

const Box = (props) => {
  const [boxStyle, setBoxStyle] = useState({})
  
  const toggleBackground = () => {
    if ('background' in boxStyle) {
      setBoxStyle({})
    } else {
      setBoxStyle({'background': 'red'})
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="box" style={boxStyle} onClick={toggleBackground}>{props.id}</div>
  )
}

const GameBoard = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      { props.children }
    </div>
  )
}

const Board = () => {
  var rows = []
  var numrows = 10;
  for(var i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
    rows.push(<Box id={"box" + i} key={`key-${i}`} tabIndex="0" />);
  }
  return (
    <GameBoard>{ rows }</GameBoard>
  )
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');
ReactDOM.render(<Board />, domContainer);
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

#### SUGGESTION:

When you are working with a reactive framework like React (or Vue), try to avoid direct DOM manipulation. These frameworks do a lot of work for you, but it's quite easy to mess up their processes if you modify something that they cannot track.

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.getElementById` is not prefered in react.

Below is a hooks representation for your code:

```js
function Row(){
    const [coloured,setColoured] = useState(false);
    const handleClick=()=>{
        setColoured(true)
    }
    return <Box style={coloured?{color:"red"}:null} tabIndex="0" onClick={handleClick} className="box"  />
}

function Board() {
    
    var numrows = 1000;
    var rows = new Array(numrows)

    return (
       <GameBoard>
           {rows.map(()=><Row />)}
       </GameBoard>
    )
}
```

You can import useState from react i.e.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
```

Comment: Yes can make any box red just by clicking on them because they are in different components so change in state of one box will not affect the state of other boxes.